# make Gradle build fail in release mode with a code that does not respect @Intdef annotations

Tags: android, gradle, annotations

The title sums it up very well.

I am using the @Intdef annotation in order to define which constants I can use as params or return values in some methods, like so :

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@IntDef({NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD, NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST, NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS})
public @interface NavigationMode {}

public static final int NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD = 0;
public static final int NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST = 1;
public static final int NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS = 2;

@NavigationMode
public  int getNavigationMode() {
    return NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST;
}

public void setNavigationMode(@NavigationMode int mode) {
    mNavigationMode = mode;
}
```

As a test, I have added this call :

```
setNavigationMode(5);
```

Android Studio shows it as an error, which is great, but I would also like to make the Gradle build check this lint rule for release builds (I don't want to lengthen debug builds with lint checks though).

So, I have added this to my build.gradle :

```
lintOptions {
        abortOnError true
        checkReleaseBuilds true
        fatal 'NewApi', 'InlineApi', 'ResourceType'
    }
```

However, Gradle compiles this project without detecting this error.
Am I missing anything ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the version 1.3.0-beta1 of the android gradle plugin, we now have a Lint check for IntDef annotations.

Comment: I'm on version 2.0 of the gradle plugin and this still does not work(?)

lintOptions {
        abortOnError true
        fatal 'ResourceType'
    }

Answer (score 2):

In a [comment on this Google+ post](https://plus.google.com/+TorNorbye/posts/Vb7zjS9fi9W) Tor Norbye explains that `ResourceType` checks are built on top of IntelliJ, and do not work with lint currently. It may in the future.